# Can you disable toolbar by default in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

In Yosemite, opening folders in a new window by default is extremely difficult.
You can press CMD as you click (not optimal) or right-click/option-click the folder to open in a new window (not optimal).

The solution that seems to work best for me is to hide the toolbar whenever I open / create a new folder, because folders inside windows that do not have a toolbar will always open in a new window.

But the toolbar always reappears whenever I create a new folder.

So, ideally, I would love to have it ALWAYS hidden by default, and on rare occasions when I need it (to look at external drives, or drag an item into the application folder for example), I would shortcut-make it appear, ta-daam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work:

- Close all open **Finder** windows
- Open a New Finder window and arrange it to your liking.
- From the Menu select **View** then **Show View Options** <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- Click the **Use as Defaults** button at the bottom.

[image: Lonely folder]

[image: View Options Dialog]

#### Toolbar

Also, the **View** Menu shows many shortcuts to toggle view options.

[image: Finder View Options Menu]

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as solved although for the moment I mostly use the shortcut that removes the sidebar cmd+alt+T

Answer (score 1):

on monterey they seem to have removed the "set as default option"

EDIT: for column view that is